# How can this loop work?

Tags: loops, python-3.x

If I have a loop that depends on two variables, for example:
while x is higher than 0 and y is higher than 0: do some stuff. but when x is equal or lower than 0 and y is still higher than 0, do stuff_X; and when x is still higher than 0 but y goes equal or lower than 0, do stuff_Y.

How can I write that in python language?
I don't know how to use "or" and "and" in python, so I think they can be useful.
I tried with "while" but I don't know how to end it.

```
while x > 0 (and?) y > 0:
    some
    stuff
    here
    if x <= 0:
        stuff_X
    if y <= 0:
        stuff_Y
```

Comment: [You just won't believe it.](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Answer (score 1):

You must use an `or`:

```
while x > 0 or y > 0:
    some
    stuff
    here
    if x <= 0:
        stuff_X
    if y <= 0:
        stuff_Y
```

It will end when both `x` and `y` are less or equal to `0`.

Comment: The OP says "while `x` is higher than 0 and `y` is higher than 0: do some stuff", so you need an `if` statement gating it, and the other `if` statements should check both variables as the "stuff" is probably rebinding `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

(can't yet comment to add onto Christian's answer) Here's a tutorial that might help you understand and/or further:

[Tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Boolean_Expressions)